# Might have accidentally deleted MongoDB database; weird error message?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried running my MongoDB after making some changes on my local git repository. Now when I try to ru the server I get the following error message:

```
    2017-04-19T20:58:51.405-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=29410 port=27017 dbpath=db/ 64-bit host=********-MacBook.local

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "db/" } }

2017-04-19T20:58:51.406-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - db/mongod.lock is not empty.

2017-04-19T20:58:51.407-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in db/ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.

2017-04-19T20:58:51.407-0400 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.

2017-04-19T20:58:51.407-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1536M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),

2017-04-19T20:58:52.568-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1492649932:568025][29410:0x7fffbc6133c0], file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: unable to read root page from file:sizeStorer.wt: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

2017-04-19T20:58:52.568-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp 69

2017-04-19T20:58:52.568-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 



***aborting after invariant() failure





2017-04-19T20:58:52.582-0400 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).



 0x10c86a54a 0x10c869d40 0x7fffb3a32bba 0xff80000000001000 0x7fffb38b9420 0x10c7deeef 0x10c605c1d 0x10c5ec5da 0x10c5ed427 0x10c5eb27f 0x10c524b8c 0x10bd57d03 0x10bd54908 0x7fffb3825255

----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----

{"backtrace":[{"b":"10BD53000","o":"B1754A","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"B16D40","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_110abruptQuitEi"},{"b":"7FFFB3A30000","o":"2BBA","s":"_sigtramp"},{"b":"0","o":"FF80000000001000"},{"b":"7FFFB385A000","o":"5F420","s":"abort"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"A8BEEF","s":"_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"8B2C1D","s":"_ZN5mongo20WiredTigerSizeStorerC2EP15__wt_connectionRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"8995DA","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mbbbb"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"89A427","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mbbbb"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"89827F","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"7D1B8C","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"4D03","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEi"},{"b":"10BD53000","o":"1908","s":"main"},{"b":"7FFFB3820000","o":"5255","s":"start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.2", "gitVersion" : "3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Darwin", "release" : "16.1.0", "version" : "Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Wed Oct 19 20:31:56 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.4~4/RELEASE_X86_64", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "path" : "/usr/local/bin/mongod", "machType" : 2, "b" : "10BD53000", "vmaddr" : "100000000", "buildId" : "41E959F86BB230BC9B95341BE293E7B5" }, { "path" : "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "10F117000", "vmaddr" : "0", "buildId" : "79FF0E4D0C493BC188856BFD213C1C3E" }, { "path" : "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "10F175000", "vmaddr" : "0", "buildId" : "323A70A18F5C35419570B46743A8CD31" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB222A000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF891AE000", "buildId" : "F62ED8CF37FB30E3A453C62BA28CAA07" }, { "path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF9E497000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF7541B000", "buildId" : "A372C4F3C48438F1947E04712740B2AD" }, { "path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFA47B6000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF7B73A000", "buildId" : "B3CE2460305A393B8B84B58B1A5B2CA7" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB23C2000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89346000", "buildId" : "BEE86868F831384C919E2B286ACFE87C" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3749000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A6CD000", "buildId" : "84E55656FDA93B299E4FBE31B2C0AA3C" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB374E000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A6D2000", "buildId" : "D2711CB22D9A32388082CDB8AE60017F" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3759000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A6DD000", "buildId" : "486BDE5281B43446BD7223977CAE556F" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3761000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A6E5000", "buildId" : "0DA49B7756EC362D98FFFA78CFD986D6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB376A000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A6EE000", "buildId" : "9846F6836CED3CE5AE8AB0A681F7FEEF" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB37ED000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A771000", "buildId" : "FDC0F71DA415306AABE8CA21E25A55BB" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3820000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7A4000", "buildId" : "7BFA347662103BCB8CE89B952F87BD84" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3826000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7AA000", "buildId" : "09CD7CA646D23A9FB9F17C4CA5CA0D68" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3834000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7B8000", "buildId" : "7AB2E2EA8B47342087CE5EE18A4EEE49" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3835000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7B9000", "buildId" : "1EAE5ADD490C3B1F9F97447BA8E0E90F" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB383B000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7BF000", "buildId" : "78EF62D8C8903FC0937AC2FD8CEF8992" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB383E000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7C2000", "buildId" : "C4FC07FFED86382EB06F33C34718080C" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3840000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7C4000", "buildId" : "2217DE860635393E93DDA1344EC0EF4B" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3859000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7DD000", "buildId" : "B8C3701D5A913D35999D2DC8D5393525" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB385A000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7DE000", "buildId" : "FB1702C3C52137BD91CB559168785D22" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB38E8000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A86C000", "buildId" : "D7FC38C6794C3C26AE4F020A72E1BB79" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB38EC000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A870000", "buildId" : "ADE57FD1AFEB3E86820DE4F28330F76A" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB38F0000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A874000", "buildId" : "8F7E9B12400D3276A9C54546B0258554" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3909000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A88D000", "buildId" : "49E37AB9776C3F848AC29BDD0438ED9D" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3910000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A894000", "buildId" : "C686B8345E7D382CAF6E44AB78EE83E2" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB393A000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A8BE000", "buildId" : "651F249FD7973FBDA66F66DFB48FCF38" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB395D000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A8E1000", "buildId" : "E3370D16EBAA3C7FAC562D6EAD7DB0A4" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB39A5000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A929000", "buildId" : "3DD17B88B7A438B99E95AB88E1C3B647" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB39C4000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A948000", "buildId" : "0F16BBE03092390E96D90B5DCC97B317" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A1C000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9A0000", "buildId" : "C8C8807BF5C1307E8D6702793B62E9ED" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A26000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9AA000", "buildId" : "D38E3A3CAEEE321A861E160ABE4B20B4" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A30000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9B4000", "buildId" : "884DDF423CAE334A82CE965617130FB1" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A39000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9BD000", "buildId" : "F35891ACCA823F979BE615EC3B4C36F6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A44000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9C8000", "buildId" : "FCF7F7C279B5321F901DA190CD3D22A2" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A48000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9CC000", "buildId" : "A54B8FEFE7923C548E0BE80A376662F2" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A4A000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9CE000", "buildId" : "B26F656E94F938349B0351C4FF11D1BF" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A52000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9D6000", "buildId" : "046443DA04743A73A69F1DC21C49B8AD" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A73000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9F7000", "buildId" : "9F7C2AD8A9A73DE4828DB0F0F166AAA0" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3A79000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A9FD000", "buildId" : "CE86F4BAEF3133BD8AC37BF25F632FA9" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB2F34000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89EB8000", "buildId" : "47104A1B13E8369FBC3627FF465809FD" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libauto.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB23A1000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89325000", "buildId" : "5BBF6A00CC76389D84E7CA88EDADE683" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB2419000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8939D000", "buildId" : "1CEF8ABB7E6D3C2F8E0AE7884478DD23" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB1FEB000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF88F6F000", "buildId" : "422911A4E2733E88BFC4DF6470E48242" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB297F000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89903000", "buildId" : "063DBF01CEF83C2E9917A08358BB006D" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3729000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A6AD000", "buildId" : "46E3FFA24328327A8D34A03E20BFFB8E" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB246B000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF893EF000", "buildId" : "F3BAB54CDA8237C3A21846FEB179D555" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB246C000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF893F0000", "buildId" : "D12709F3BBE33CF79070C2A0803F5526" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB23A2000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89326000", "buildId" : "20084796B04D3B35A003EA11459557A9" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB35FE000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A582000", "buildId" : "AAFCF32181003622880B9661DCA35D69" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB33CB000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A34F000", "buildId" : "A531C10564D737C0B9999320047B71C5" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB330C000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A290000", "buildId" : "352F8FF622483594B3578D031DEFB06C" }, { "path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFA0471000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF773F5000", "buildId" : "F1B84DE8125731EBBF8D840341627831" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB2224000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF891A8000", "buildId" : "D025E180BB3B3FFA98FCB6835354D723" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB23B3000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89337000", "buildId" : "6FD3B63F0F863A25BD5BE243F58792C9" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB360F000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A593000", "buildId" : "2667615564CE323FB73CAD77AF5982E8" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB2BAC000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF89B30000", "buildId" : "44BD027999DD36B58A6EC11432E2098D" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB2876000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF897FA000", "buildId" : "A1B040A2797730979ADF34FF181EB970" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFFB3827000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF8A7AB000", "buildId" : "95D9F58B735C35889736B2B761D6D8CF" } ] }}

 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE+0x3A) [0x10c86a54a]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_110abruptQuitEi+0xC0) [0x10c869d40]

 libsystem_platform.dylib(_sigtramp+0x1A) [0x7fffb3a32bba]

 ??? [0xff80000000001000]

 libsystem_c.dylib(abort+0x81) [0x7fffb38b9420]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j+0x31F) [0x10c7deeef]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo20WiredTigerSizeStorerC2EP15__wt_connectionRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE+0x22D) [0x10c605c1d]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mbbbb+0xB9A) [0x10c5ec5da]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mbbbb+0x37) [0x10c5ed427]

 mongod(_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE+0x15F) [0x10c5eb27f]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x64C) [0x10c524b8c]

 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEi+0x743) [0x10bd57d03]

 mongod(main+0x358) [0x10bd54908]

 libdyld.dylib(start+0x1) [0x7fffb3825255]

-----  END BACKTRACE  -----

Abort trap: 6
```

It possible for me to replace the database, but as you can guess, that is a major pain. I don't have my database synced with git because it is a large file (I'm dumb I know). I do have Time Machine running so I do have the physical data, but the same error message from above happens every time I try to run based off of a backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Time Machine backup of a live MongoDB database is not going to be a reliable backup, as it will not ensure that all of the individual data files are in a consistent state. It's possible that you could get very lucky and have a particular backup where the files are consistent, but not in this case.

In the future I'd suggest that you either stop MongoDB before running backup or [fsyncLock()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/).

**EDIT**:

As I mentioned in a comment, you might also try following [this procedure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) to start mongod with the --repair option. It's not guaranteed to work in every case, but somewhat surprisingly it worked in this case.

Comment: Is there any way to check if a Time Machine backup caught the database when it is in a static state? Or any way to trick Mongo into giving up the documents?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'd brute force try a few different backups and see if it starts clean.

Comment: You could try --repair, but I wouldn't get your hopes up. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

Comment: My suggestion is to lock the DB and use a backup program like Carbon Copy Cloner to an attached external disk. Also consider BackBlaze. Personally I use all three: two TmeMachine drives, one internal, one AirPort Time Capsule; CarbonCopyCloner to RAID5 storage; BackBlaze and a couple other extras.

Comment: @helmy You've it! --repair worked perfectly, and we're back and booming!

Comment: That's great @NickHuff, I've updated my answer to include --repair. If you wouldn't mind, please mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See:
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)